# How to stub private method without powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, junit5

I have a class with a private method that calls some external class and executes it, how can I prevent this without using powermock? (the project uses Junit5 which at this point does not not support powermock yet).

I considered moving these functions outside, but I feel that sometimes methods really belong in a particular class because they are part of it, and it makes no sense to me to move them out, below is just an example to illustrate.

I already know most people will say not to test private methods, but a. I don't completely agree, and b. I'm not trying to test the method here, just to prevent it executing an external call, even to a fake api url.

```
public class GenericOauth2Client implements Oauth2Client {
  private NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
  private JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY;

  public GenericOauth2Client(<some_args>) {
    ...
    HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
  }


  public foo(<some_args>) {
            ...
    fetchRefreshTokenResponse( < some_args >);
            ...
  }

  private TokenResponse fetchRefreshTokenResponse(<some_args>)
      throws IOException {
    return new RefreshTokenRequest(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new GenericUrl(tokenServerUrl),
        refreshToken.tokenValue)
        .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication(clientId, clientSecret))
        .execute();
  }
}
```

How can this be handled / tested properly?

Comment: what is HTTP_TRANSPORT? can you supply another one which will recognize url and prevent network call?

Comment: it's a new NetHttpTransport, please see updated question.

Comment: Make a new package private constructor that is able to inject a mocked NetHttpTransport

Comment: In fact, your test should be able to use the provided mock class https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/testing/http/MockHttpTransport.java

Answer (score 0):

My approach is usually to make the method protected and create a little helper class for the test which derives from the class under test and override the protected method with a stub implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make another constructor for it that's not public. Also "program to the interface" so that you can inject behavior more easily

```
public class GenericOauth2Client implements Oauth2Client {
  private HttpTransport transport;
  private JsonFactory jsonFactory;

  public GenericOauth2Client(<some_args>) {
    ...
    transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  }

   GenericOauth2Client(<some_args>, HttpTransport t) {
    this(args);
    transport = t;
  }
```

Alternatively, if you have no control over the http client, but can change the url, then WireMock would be the other option to mock the server responses